# Need an alternative to frames

Tags: html, frames

I need an alternative to frames. My layout is as follows, a hovering menu bar and a web page below. The menu has a text box where i can enter the url which is loaded in the other frame. now any url i click on this frame should be loaded inside this frame only. The problem i'm facing is that a significant number of sites do not allow their sites to be loaded inside frames due to fear of clickjacking i suppose. So i'm desperately looking for an alternative to frames, by which i can still do what i stated above. Is that possible? Any and every help will be truely appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Your best bet is an iframe.  The only option that is better is an addon to the users browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing *is* frames (either using `<frameset>` or `<iframe>`). There is no alternative, and both are treated more or less identically from a browser security standpoint.